# Got only isalnum_t function with ctype

Tags: c

I have only `isalnum_t` function with `ctype`; I expect function `isalnum` so what is going on?
I include `ctype` and this function is what I need for check alpha and digit is declared as `isalnum_t(int, _locale_t)`.  I searched on the internet but can't find this function; Google redirects me "Do you mean isalnum?"

*** My past question was something similar with this about `getline`. I declared my `getline` and compiler get me notify that it got declared previous, (I include only `<stdio.h>`); what is problem?

UPDATE:

1. Sorry for no info. Using Ubuntu and Code Blocks.
2. Why need to show code, cause code don't change lib, like I said. (I include only `ctype` and `stdio` headers.)
3. I was very fast, so I didn't compile code with `isalnum`; in that way it successful compile, but and further can someone explain me what is `isalnum_t` function? I got it in list when I start typing (is...) ? And this for `getline`?

Comment: show your code.Also `getline` is not c function

Comment: How do you know the isalnum() function is not available ? Please post your code. Then tell us what happens when you compile that code, e.g. copy/paste any compiler errors you get so we can see them.

Comment: Please also advise on your platform. GCC? MS C? Version?

Comment: Is it really `isalnum_t` and not `isalnum_l`?

Comment: Your IDE is leading you astray.  If you want to use `isalnum()`, use it.  It exists.  It is usually defined as a macro, but the C Standard requires that it is implemented as a function too.  The `isalnum_t(int, _locale_t)` variant looks like an alternative interface that takes a locale as well as the character code so that you can test whether the character is alphanumeric in different locales without setting the current locale for everything (simplifying somewhat).  You probably don't need it.

Comment: If you did include <ctype.h> , you should be able to use `isalnum`. Your IDE might have some problems here.

Comment: Tnx guys, but what with getline?

Comment: You need POSIX C for that, or GNU C, it is in <stdio.h> . But it is not so portable. If you would like to stay portable, and not rely on POSIX, or GNU extensions, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `getline()` function is specified by [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html). You can use the GCC compiler option [`-std=`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) as in `-std=c99` to be able to define your own function with this name. By default (`gnu90` or `gnu11` in the future) GCC [requests](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) all those POSIX functions and many other stuff to be be made visible. But I recommend simply using another identifier, that isn't already used/reserved by ISO C or POSIX, to avoid issues as the one you're currently experiencing.

`isalnum_l()` (I think you made a typo) is specified by the same [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isalnum.html). Unlike `isalnum()` it takes two arguments as opposed to only one. With this additional argument of type `locale_t`, you're able to test if a character is alphanumeric in a specific locale. `isalnum()` is limited to the current locale.

Comment: The `_l` suffix is certainly more normal for functions that take a locale argument; I hadn't suspected a typo since it was repeated, but the more I think about it, the more you're likely to be right. _[…and a quick check in an Ubuntu VM shows `isalnum_l` and no `isalnum_t`…]_